# Get NSImage from NSGradient with Cocoa (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am looking for an extension to create a `NSImage` from a `NSGradient` object with Cocoa (macOS) in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in Swift 5:

```swift
extension NSImage {
    convenience init?(gradientColors: [NSColor], imageSize: NSSize) {
        guard let gradient = NSGradient(colors: gradientColors) else { return nil }
        let rect = NSRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imageSize)
        self.init(size: rect.size)
        let path = NSBezierPath(rect: rect)
        self.lockFocus()
        gradient.draw(in: path, angle: 0.0)
        self.unlockFocus()
    }
}
```